# ForEach Item in variable - get it's value

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a script which has three Textboxes in it where the User can put in Information. After he put in the information, they are stored in a variable like this:

```
$v = $test.text
$t = $test2.text
$w = $test3.text
$vtw = $v, $t, $w

ForEach ($Item in $vtw) {Write-Host "Hello"}
```

How can I get `Write-Host` to put out the value of each variable in `$vtw`?

At the moment it is this output

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

I want this one (actually the value of those)

```
$test.text
$test2.test
$test3.text
```

I tried it like this, but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

```
$v = $test.text
$t = $test2.text
$w = $test3.text
$vtw = $v, $t, $w

ForEach ($Item in $vtw) {Write-Host $Item}
```

Comment: `ForEach ($Item in $vtw) {Write-Host $Item}` is the correct syntax. Check the value of `$Item` first maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're joining strings

```
$vtw = $v, $t, $w
```

You should be creating an array: classified with "@"

```
$vtw = @($v,$t,$w)
```

Comment: Uhm, that's exactly the same result for both lines, actually. The first one also creates an array.

Comment: @Joey quotes in those strings were fudging was my assumption